# fseek behavior with binary file

Tags: c, file-io, binaryfiles, binary-data

I'm working with a binary format.

I've noticed that

```
fseek(fp, offset, SEEK_SET);
fread(&mystruct, sizeof(struct mystruct_thing), 1, fp);
```

produces output that's different from simply

```
fread(&mystruct, sizeof(struct mystruct_thing), 1, fp);
```

which follows expected behavior.

Why is this the case? Is it because `SEEK_SET` overrides the offset parameter?

Comment: `SEEK_SET` is the beginning of the file and the offset is bytes past the beginning (including 0).  For example, if `offset == sizeof(mystruct)`, `fp` is pointing to the address `SEEK_SET + sizeof(mystruct)`.

Comment: consider replacing `sizeof(struct mystruct_thing)` with `sizeof mystruct`. Much more readyble and obviously correct, even if you later change the type.

Comment: @Deduplicator Agreed, although from the use of `&mystruct` it seems that `sizeof mystruct` would be correct rather than `sizeof *mystruct`.

Answer (score 2):

The second argument of `fread` is the size of each item to be read, in this case the `struct`. I don't understand how you would expect the offset to go there – it should be something like `sizeof(mystruct)`.

**Edit**: Now that the question has been edited, the reason why the two pieces of code produce different results is simply that the first one seeks the position of `fp` to `offset` before reading and the second one doesn't. `fread` reads `sizeof(struct mystruct_thing)` bytes *starting from the current position* of `fp`, so the starting position differs (assuming `offset` is not the same position at which you are already at before `fseek`) because `fseek` sets the position *for future reads* (and writes).

Comment: @William Even after the edit your second piece of code has `offset` as the second argument.

Comment: @Arkku : This is not an *answer* - it should have been posted as a *comment*.  Now William has fixed the question, this makes no sense at all.

Comment: @William Ok, but after the edit the question makes no sense anymore, because the second piece of code doesn't refer to `offset`, and hence cannot be expected to read from that offset.

Comment: @Clifford It was an answer as to why the code in the question, as originally posted, produced different results, i.e., there was a misunderstanding of what the parameters of `fread` are. Now the _question_ makes no more sense.

Comment: Perhaps, but is was obviously nonsense since he'd said that the invalid code produced *expected* results.  Critiquing or clarifying questions is for comments.  In any case not your fault, rather the poor quality of the original question.  You should now perhaps update the answer or delete it.

Comment: @Clifford I've updated the answer. Also, if `offset` was equal to `sizeof mystruct` in the original question, then it would have been understandable that the second piece of code produced expected result, i.e., it would have been a misunderstanding of how `fread` and/or `fseek` work. That is what I answered to.

Comment: I have removed my down-vote as this is now an answer, but I would remove the original text and the reference to the original question being edited and let the answer stand alone - change history is adequately managed by SO and can be viewed by anyone interested.

Answer (score 0):

The first fragment will read a struct from `offset` bytes into the file, the second fragment will read it from the current file position - if the file has just been opened, that will be zero.

The obvious explanation perhaps is that `offset` is not equal to zero.